# Can't download the snap packages

Tags: snap

I can't download the snap packages.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

[image]

Comment: That looks like a temporary store issue. Have you tried again?

Comment: I have tried it for days.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy by any chance? There's a fix that makes snapd respect proxy settings. It's already merged but it is not released yet. It will likely show up in snapd 2.0.6

For now you can edit the systemd unit of snapd and add

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

And obviously ensure that your proxy settings are stored in /etc/environment.

Comment: I'm not using the proxy now.

Comment: I have solved the problem, just typed "snap login 'email' "

Comment: Please update your question with an answer so others can find it more easily